# Error in Xcode 7: None of the input catalogs contained a matching launch image set

Tags: xcode

I have a LaunchImage asset with the proper type (launch image), and it has all the required sizes for the purpose of the app. When building an archive before submission to the App Store, I get the following error message:

```
/the/path/to/media.xcassets: None of the input catalogs
contained a matching launch image set named  "LaunchImage".
```

It was working in Xcode 6 and it is not working anymore in Xcode 7, even though I have not changed anything.

It appears in 'red' in the build settings, as if the asset was missing, but it is in the assets, see screenshot. When I click on the red name, my only option is to 'not use assets'.

[image: Build settings]

[image: Assets in Xcode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is a bug with Xcode 7: image assets cannot be inside a folder, and my launch image asset was inside a folder, as you can see in the screenshot. It was working fine in Xcode 6, so I assume it is a bug in the newer version.

The workaround was to move the asset out of the folder into the parent root content area. The build settings then correctly show the asset in black, and the build does not fail anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Select your image asset, open the file inspector on the right side, go into Target Membership and deselect all the check marks and enable your target app for which you have added icons.